# number of lists of increasing integers

Tags: combinatorics

How many lists are there of five increasing numbers ranging from 1 to 100?
Examples would be 1,2,56,77,90 and 5,8,34,35,37.  Is this easily calculated?

Comment: are they strictly increasing, or weakly increasing ? that could affect the result ( I'm just clarifying, even though all your example are strictly increasing).

Answer (score 1):

There is a total of $100*99*98*97*96$ was to pick 5 numbers from 1 to 100. This includes cases where the numbers are the same, but in a different order.

Of all the cases where 5 set numbers are chosen, only 1 will be increasing. There are $5!$ ways to organize that set, so the answer is 
$$\frac{100*99*98*97*96}{5*4*3*2*1}$$

EDIT: for a general case where we pick $n$ numbers from $1$ to $x$

$$\frac{x!}{(x-n)!*n!} = {x \choose n}$$

Comment: Each term is greater than the previous term.  The smallest list is

Comment: the smallest list is 1,2,3,4,5 and the largest is 96,97,98,99,100.

Comment: @J.M.Bergot and ?

Comment: I think he means it's strictly increasing but he replied to mine instead of the question.

Comment: I find it simpler to consider to skip the intermediate step and consider at once that there is a bijection between the number of situations you are looking for and the number of subsets with 5 elements among $\{1,2,3,\cdots,99,100 \}$ which is known to be $\binom{100}{5}$ (once such a subset is selected, it is naturally ordered in a unique way).

Comment: If two answers are the same, then I do thank you.

Comment: @Jean Marie I didn't realize that it would just be choosing at first.

Comment: The sum of all the numbers in the 75,287,520,lists is 19,010,098,800, which is about one-thousandth of the US national debt.